# convert arrays to a single array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have these 3 sets of arrays:

```
var name = ["john", "peter", "rick"];
var age = [20, 45, 30];
var country = ["Brazil", "USA", "Italy"];
```

I need to combine into a single array of objects and get this result:

```
 var result = [{
'name':'John',
'age':20,
'country': 'Brazil'},
{ 
 'name':'peter',
 'age':45,
 'country': 'USA'},
 {
'name':'Rick',
'age':30,
'country': 'Italy'}
];
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all yourself yet?

Comment: yes, I did, but I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are all in the same order, you can do this:

```
var firstname = ["john", "peter", "rick"];
var age = [20, 45, 30];
var country = ["Brazil", "USA", "Italy"];
var array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < firstname.length; i++) {
    array.push({firstname: firstname[i], age: age[i], country: country[i]});
}
console.log( JSON.stringify(array) );
```

Note that I changed `name` into `firstname`: for some reason, it didn't work with `name`, possibly because it is a reserved term in Javascript or the browser.